# Is there any scenario where a fragment is destroyed without the activity and without transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle

Is there any scenario where a fragment is destroyed without the host activity and without transaction ?

> do you mean that there was never a transaction related to hiding that fragment?

yes

Comment: By "without transaction" do you mean that there was _never_ a transaction related to hiding that fragment, or rather do you mean that there was no explicit transaction asking to destroy the fragment?

Comment: Also, what does "without the activity" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare without the host activity being destroyed

Comment: @BenP. updated the question

Comment: I cannot think of a scenario where a fragment can be destroyed without the associated activity being destroyed or some transaction having taken effect.

Comment: me nether, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If your `Fragment` is in the "foreground" (i.e. it's currently added to an activity), it can only be destroyed in two scenarios. First, the `Activity` might be destroyed (a configuration change or the system reclaiming resources). Second, you might execute some `FragmentTransaction` to destroy it (e.g. a `replace()` call).

If your `Fragment` is in the "background" (e.g. you previously executed a transaction using `addToBackStack()`) it can be destroyed without the `Activity` also being destroyed (if the system wants to reclaim resources). But I believe this does not meet your definition of "without transaction". I just want to call attention to the fact that the `Fragment` might be destroyed some amount of time *after* the transaction is executed (as opposed to immediately upon execution).

tl;dr: No, a `Fragment` can't be destroyed unless its host `Activity` is destroyed or you've executed a transaction to remove it at some point in the past.